# Passing an function array to a button.onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have trouble with TypeScript/JavaScript

I have an array of function like this

```
private listeners: ((name: string) => void)[] = [];
```

I'm adding functions to it in another function that seems to work.

now I want to call those functions if a button is pressed

```
button.onclick = function(){
   this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
}
```

if I try my code this way nothing happens, I bet it is because it doesn't know `listeners`.

my next try was

```
button.onclick = function(listeners){
       listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
}
```

Now tsc tells me

> error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.

I bet I'm missing a type here, but idk how to tell him that this array is an array of functions of type `((name: string) => void)[] = [];`

Would be cool if someone knows a quick workaround.
Before you ask: I'm sure that my function added functions to my array (at least in the add function the size of `listerns` got bigger) :D

Comment: You must be describing some object, but we have no idea what it is. Your guesses aren't working out because `this` will be a reference to the element itself and your function parameter receives the event object. So maybe you could give us a complete yet minimal example of this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? I assume it generates a console error--did you look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your onclick handler like this to keep 'this' pointing to the current class instance:

```
private onClick(ev)
{
    this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
}

//Then somewhere later 
button.onclick = (ev) => this.onClick(ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that `this` doesn't refer to your expected context. Instead, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) refers to the `MouseEvent` context of your click handler.

As a simple solution for your problem you might use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Change

```
button.onclick = function(){ 
   this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
}
```

To this

```
button.onclick = function(){ 
   this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
}.bind(this);
```

Basic explanation:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated way of dealing with your issue is not to use `onclick` at all, but rather `addEventListener`, and you can use the following little-known approach of passing an object with a `handleEvent` method to `addEventListener`, which makes all your issues with `this` moot:

```
class Foo {

  private listeners: ((name: string) => void)[] = [];

  constructor(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', this);
  }

  handleEvent(event) {
    // check event type
    this.listeners.forEach(callback => callback(username));
  }

}

const new Foo(document.getElementById('myButton'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the awnsers

i guess that a direct add of a function wont work because its an Eventhandler function, which works somewhere in the code but not there where i defined it.

I changed to addeventhandler and defined with let a function inside my function, and call a new function for the Eventhandler which calls the function it should call.#funcception :D

```
let triggerOnClick = () => {
        let username = tf_name.value;
        this.listeners.forEach((callback) => callback(username));
    };

    btn_enter.addEventListener("click", () => {
        triggerOnClick();
    });
```

that code works :)